# Replace zeros of percentage of zeros in column is less then 50

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to create an evaluator. If the percentage of zeros in one column is less then 50% then replace zeroes with mean.

I tried everything that I cant think of but nothing works.

```
i = 0
if (1-((df1.iloc[:, i] == 0).astype(float).sum(axis=0)/df1.iloc[:, i].count())) > 0.5:    
    df1.iloc[:, i] = df1.iloc[:, i].mask(df1.iloc[:, i]==0).fillna(df1.iloc[:, i].mean())              
    i = i+1
else:
    i = i+1
```

```
def Zeros(i):
    if (1-((df1.iloc[:, i] == 0).astype(float).sum(axis=0)/df1.iloc[:, i].count())) > 0.5:    
        df1.iloc[:, i] = df1.iloc[:, i].mask(df1.iloc[:, i]==0).fillna(df1.iloc[:, i].mean())              
        i = i+1
    else:
        i = i+1
        return
Zeros(0)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `pandas`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
i = 0
if df[i].value_counts()[0] / len(df) < 0.5:
    df.iloc[df['i'] == 0, i] = df[i].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exclude = ['c', 'f']

def Zeros(i):
    while i < len(df1.columns):
        if df1.columns[i] in exclude:
            i = i+1
        elif (1-((df1.iloc[:, i] == 0).astype(float).sum(axis=0)/df1.iloc[:, i].count())) > 0.5:    
            df1.iloc[:, i] = df1.iloc[:, i].mask(df1.iloc[:, i]==0).fillna(df1.iloc[:, i].mean())              
            i = i+1
        else:
            i = i+1
    return
Zeros(0)
```